# (The image is not yet found)Image Uploading to Database while The Site is at Web Host

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing, hosting

This code was run on my localhost. The images are uploaded to my mysql server using the localhost wampserver. Everything seems to be good. But when I migrate the code to the hosting site, I can't see the image uploaded in the mysql server. All I can see is my path "images-storage/" as the value of "photo" column,  "images-storage" is empty and no image is stored.

This is the code:

My Form:

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br />
    Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br /><br />
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My form action:

```
<?php
    include_once('config.php');

    $fn = $_POST['firstname'];
    $ln = $_POST['lastname'];
    $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $type = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $size = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
    $temp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $error = $_FILES["image"]["error"];

    if($error > 0) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        $add_image = move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
        $path = 'uploaded/'.$name;
        $query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO info(fn,ln,name,photo) VALUES('$fn','$ln','$name','$path')");  
    }

    header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: When you log onto your remote system, and navigate to `images-storage/`, what result do you get when you run `ls -la`? (This may be a permissions issue.) Generally, though, what does your php on the remote server show? Any errors or fatals?

Comment: Sir I already solved this thing. Thank you sir. :)

Comment: You should post a solution, then! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add "name" column in the database. Haha